# getExtensionValue x509certificate null reference?

Tags: c#, api, bouncycastle, x509, windows-store

It's showing exception

```cs
byte[] bytes = cert.GetExtensionValue(new DerObjectIdentifier(oid)).GetOctets();
```

But as you can see in my code. everything is okay. The oid was returned normally. What can be the problem?
Below are the pictures of different versions of code.

Picture 1:
[image: picture 1]

Picture 2:
[image: picture 2]

Comment: Apparently, there is no such extension.

Comment: Everything is not ok. You are trying to call the `.getOctets()` method on a null reference.

Comment: I see extaValue is null.But why? I read the certificate from smartcard.It's ID card of Armenia. Need to validate by OCSP.

Comment: Please follow [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) on [ask] and post the relevant code as text.